# Bounding box for each letter

Tags: pdftex, luatex, boxes

How can I take input text and replace each character with a solid (and/or hollow) rectangle representing the bounding box for that character? In the case where two characters are closer together from kerning (e.g. `microtype`) the boxes would overlap. The addition of the boxes should not change the spacing of the text - I'm looking for a "draft mode" for the letters.

## Solutions and Problems

Both solutions presented by Yiannis Lazarides and egreg seem to do a reasonable job for single words, though as mentioned, it seems that kerning was not completely respected. Below are the results (without markup/egreg/Yiannis):

[image]

Both solutions fail however when multiple words are involved. One of the answers completely eats a space while the other overcompensates. Both of them seem to choke on a line break as well.

[image]

Comment: this is quite similar to Exercise 11.5 from The TeXbook. Knuth provides a solution- not sure about posting it here though because of copyright...

Comment: Am pretty sure there is a question here doing exactly this but can't seem to locate it...

Comment: @cmhughes The code of the TeXbook is available for study and quoting a passage from a book is always allowed (with proper attribution).

Comment: fwiw, vafa khalighi has created a package showcharinbox which answers this (nearly 2-months-old) question. see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showcharinbox

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A LuaTeX solution. Should work in all situations that I am aware of:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
local GLYPH_ID = node.id("glyph")

local number_sp_in_a_pdf_point = 65782

function math.round(num)
  return math.floor(num * 1000 + 0.5) / 1000
end

-- width/height/depth of a glyph and the whatsit node
local wd,ht,dp,w

-- head is a linked list (next/prev entries pointing to the next node)
function showcharbox(head)
  while head do
    if head.id == 0 or head.id == 1 then
      -- a hbox/vbox
      showcharbox(head.list)
    elseif head.id == GLYPH_ID then
      -- Create a pdf_literal node to draw a box with the dimensions
      -- of the glyph
      w = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
      wd = math.round(head.width  / number_sp_in_a_pdf_point)
      ht = math.round(head.height / number_sp_in_a_pdf_point)
      dp = math.round(head.depth  / number_sp_in_a_pdf_point)

      -- draw a dashed line if depth not zero
      if dp ~= 0 then
        w.data = string.format("q 0.2 G 0.1 w 0 %g %g %g re S f [0.2] 0 d 0 0 m %g 0 l S Q",-dp,-wd,dp + ht,-wd)
      else
        w.data = string.format("q 0.2 G 0.1 w 0 %g %g %g re S f Q",-dp,-wd,dp + ht,-wd)
      end
      -- insert this new node after the current glyph and move pointer (head) to
      -- the new whatsit node
      w.next = head.next
      w.prev = head
      head.next = w
      head = w
    end
    head = head.next
  end
  return true
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",showcharbox,"showcharbox")
\end{luacode*}

A \emph{wonderful} serenity has taken {\large possession} of my entire soul, like these
\textsl{sweet}
\textbf{mornings} of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the
charm of existence in this spot, \textbf{which} was created for the bliss of souls like
mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of
mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of
drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was
a greater artist than now.

\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image: text with boxes]

(detail)

[image: detail on text with boxes]

Bonus: it draws the base line if the depth of the glyph is not 0.

---

Here is a solution that replaces the glyphs by black rectangles (rules):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase,microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
local GLYPH_ID = node.id("glyph")

-- head is a linked list (next/prev entries pointing to the next node)
-- parent it the surrounding h/vbox
function showcharbox(head,parent)
  while head do
    if head.id == 0 or head.id == 1 then
      -- a hbox/vbox
      showcharbox(head.list,head)
    elseif head.id == GLYPH_ID then
      r = node.new("rule")
      r.width  = head.width
      r.height = head.height
      r.depth  = head.depth

      -- replace the glyph by
      -- the rule by changing the
      -- pointers of the next/prev
      -- entries of the rule node
      if not head.prev then
        -- first glyph in a list
        parent.list = r
      else
        head.prev.next = r
      end

      if head.next then
        head.next.prev = r
      end
      r.prev = head.prev
      r.next = head.next

      -- now the glyph points to
      -- nowhere and we should remove
      -- it from the memory
      node.free(head)

      head = r
    end
    head = head.next
  end
  return true
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",showcharbox,"showcharbox")
\end{luacode*}

\hsize6cm

A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet
mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the
charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like
mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of
mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of
drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was
a greater artist than now.

\end{document}
```

[image: glyphs replaced by black rules]

Comment: Really nice solution!

Comment: Glad to see you back! Thanks for the great solution - this works great! How would you modify the code to draw a filled rectangle instead of a hollow one?

Comment: I've just fixed an embarrassing rounding error in my code

Comment: @Hooked Just change the `re S f` in the `w.data` lines above to `re b`. Please note that I have updated my code in the mean time.

Comment: Actually the solution with boxes is a bit easier, except for the pointer management.

Comment: Big +1 b/c it works in math mode too!

Comment: @topskip. Is it possible to adapt the solution to print only the baseline rules? Or maybe only the box around the whole line?

Comment: @Sigur do you know the package [lua-visual-debug](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua-visual-debug)? It might be what you are after, or it might be a starting point to adapt it for yourself.

Comment: @topskip, ow, thanks so much. I didn't know it. It is exactly what I need. Unfortunately it requires `luatex`. Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur well, LuaTeX makes it easy to draw these lines. PDFTeX and other engines are completely lacking this kind of support. So there is no way I could implement this behaviour for other engines.

Comment: @topskip both examples do not seem to work any more (at least here) using TL2017: both compile fine but the result differs - no boxes are shown. Do you have an idea why? Thx!

Comment: @lAtExFaN This code had hard coded codes for glyph ids (37 in older versions of LuaTeX), I have now used a function to determine the id which works with older versions as well. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: @topskip now it works (again) - thx a lot!

Comment: @topskip I tried to apply the code on my book (class: scrbook) which uses footnotes, citations, different fonts, tables etc.pp. Most of the text is boxed (footnotes, tables, font switches, quotes citatation), but some parts are not, e.g. some paragraphs (often after a footnote), the same with scrlttr class: approximately 98% of the text is boxed, but sometimes, again often after normal footnotes (not citations footnotes) the paragraph isn't tetrisified ;-) Have you successfully applied the code to a more complex document? If I find some time I try to assemble an MWE and open a new question.

Comment: @lAtExFaN This code is just a proof of concept. If you can create a MWE, just try to contact me somehow, and I'll have a look.

Comment: @topskip thx a lot for you assistance, before I take the time to construct an MWE I thought I just try to compile the first demo thesis I could find: https://math.berkeley.edu/~vojta/thesis/ and bingo! It shows the previously mentioned result (approx. 98% is fine, ~2% is "unbricked"). Please let me know if I should open up a new question.

Comment: @lAtExFaN Please open a new question and ping me somehow

Comment: @topskip ping: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/391543/112503

Answer (score 23):

Here is a solution that respects kerning (but not ligatures):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\showboxes#1{%
  \begingroup\fboxrule=.1pt \fboxsep=-\fboxrule
  \@showboxes#1\@showboxes\@empty
  \endgroup}
\def\@showboxes#1#2{%
  \ifx#2\@showboxes
    \fbox{\color{gray}#1}\expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \setbox0=\hbox{#1\kern0pt#2}\setbox2=\hbox{#1#2}%
    \dimen0=\wd0 \advance\dimen0 -\wd2 % \dimen0 contains the kern between the two chars
    \fbox{\color{gray}#1}\kern-\dimen0
    \expandafter\@showboxes
  \fi#2}
\begin{document}
\showboxes{AVov}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For doing more words just add

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\def\showboxesaux#1{\showboxes{#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand\Showboxes{>{\SplitList{ }}m}
  {\ProcessList{#1}\showboxesaux\unskip}
```

and use

```
\Showboxes{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.}
```

but hyphenation won't be taken care of.

Comment: Great solution! Can this be modified to accept multiple words? At the moment the spaces are swallowed. (See question update).

Comment: @Hooked It can, but I don't think it can be a substitute for the "real thing", that is, doing this with LuaTeX.

Comment: Excuse my Lua-ignorance, are you saying that a LuaTeX solution would be able to handle the bounding box problem in a more robust way?

Comment: @Hooked I'm sure it is (but I can't give a solution). You were unlucky that our main LuaTeX expert, Patrick Gundlach, is on his well deserved holidays.

Comment: This solution doesn't work with `xetex` as is. Wouldn't it be better to replace `\setbox0=\hbox{{#1}{#2}}` by `\setbox0=\hbox{#1\kern0pt#2}`, because `xetex` doesn't parse the grouping as expected for unknown reason?

Comment: @HenriMenke Good catch, thanks. XeTeX builds boxes in a slightly different way than Knuth's TeX (and the other engines based on it); for instance one can't do `\showhyphens` in XeTeX.

Answer (score 19):

Probably the best is the code from the TeXbook and this I will leave up to you. Another alternative is to study the code from the `soul` package and use the scanners provided.

Here is an adaptation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul,graphicx,xcolor}
\fboxrule=0.1pt
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@soeverytoken{%
  \fbox{\color{gray}\the\SOUL@token}}
\makeatother
\scalebox{7}{\color{purple}\so{ailbcdefgh}}
\end{document}
```

Change the gray color to white to have the letters disappear.

[image]

You will need to change the `\fbox` to basic TeX primitives, if you need to compensate for the 0.1pt rule or use the suggestion of egreg in the comments, which I have incorporated.

Comment: `\fboxsep=-\fboxrule` would solve the issue. But you lose kerning information in this way.

Comment: @egreg Thanks I added your code. Best is to go to a Knuth-box (I had it as a macro somewhere ...)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Thank you for the solution, I'll have to play around with `soul` a bit more. I've updated my question based off your solution, it seems that in addition your interword spacing is too large as well.

Comment: I remember I saw something like this in `fontchart.tex`

Comment: I like this solution, but it doesn't work well for math mode.  `\so{$(f+g)'(x) = f'(x)+g'(x)$}` just puts everything in one box.

Comment: For some expressions, it seems to work if the dollar signs are put outside of the \so command

Answer (score 7):

With `context` from current TeXLive

```
\setuppagenumbering[location={}]
\definepapersize[DE][width=15cm,height=15cm]
\setuppapersize [DE][DE]
\setuplayout[width=13cm,height=13cm]
\definefontfeature[default][default][boundingbox={frame,blue,empty}]
\starttext
\bgroup
    \showglyphs
    \showfontkerns
    \showmakeup[hbox]
    \showmakeup[line]
%    \showallmakeup

    »Tee for Two« shows negative kerning.
    \input sapolsky \par
\egroup
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anything that context does _not_ have built in?