# Bounding box for each symbol in an equation

Tags: math-mode, boxes

Is it possible to make LaTeX put a bounding box around each element in an equation, as in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57812/bounding-box-for-each-letter) file? I am aware of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57812/bounding-box-for-each-letter) question, but none of the solutions presented there, which does not require LuaTeX, seem to work within equations containing, e.g., commands like `\sum`.

I have tried to resolve this "manually" by putting a framebox around each symbol within an equation, but neither that seems to work for commands like `\sum`, even though it do work for simpler symbols such as digits, such as

```
\fboxrule=.1pt \fboxsep=-\fboxrule
$\framebox[\width]{1}$
```

Comment: Framebox holds it argument i text-mode no matter where it It is used. You might want to have a look at the \boxed command from amsmath

Comment: @daleif this does not work either, as it makes a separate math environment for each symbol, making it impossible to have say the subscripts of an integral in a separate box, as writing $\boxed{\sum}_ {1 \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq n}$ places the subscripts incorrectly and $\boxed{\sum}_\boxed{1 \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq n}$ does not work at all.

Comment: @malin There's no way to do it in pure TeX, unless you're ready to reimplement math mode with boxes and glue after reading appendix G of the TeXbook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach is by no means automated, but can be made to manually work.  It uses a `\boxxed` macro for putting things in boxes.  However, manual intervention is still needed as follows: `\mathop` and `\mathrel` have to be manually introduced for a boxed operator or relation, since the box removes any memory of that.

The `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` syntax of the `scalerel` package is used to preserve `\scriptstyle` arguments in their proper style, once inside the box.

The good news is that the kerning is preserved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\fboxrule=.1pt
\fboxsep=-.1pt
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\boxxed[1]{{\ThisStyle{\fbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}}}}
\begin{document} 
\( \mathop{\boxxed{\sum}}_\boxxed{i}^\boxxed{n} \boxxed{A}^\boxxed{2}\)

\( \sum_i^n A^2\)

\( \displaystyle\mathop{\boxxed{\sum}}_\boxxed{i}^\boxxed{n} \boxxed{A}^\boxxed{2}\)

\( \displaystyle\sum_i^n A^2\)
\end{document}
```

[image]