# Multi-layered Goudy Initials with Lettrine

Tags: xetex, lettrine, drop-cap

I bought the font LTC Goudy Initials from P22---as per the comment to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/372790/102323)---but now I wonder how to use this font with the package `lettrine`.

Below in my minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load the three layers of the LTC Goudy Initials font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\firstlayer{LTCGoudyInitNew.otf}
\newfontface\secondlayer{LTCGoudyInitFlora.otf}
\newfontface\thirdlayer{LTCGoudyInitFill.otf}

% Create a command to print all three layers - later in color
\newcommand{\initialmaker}[1]{%
  \firstlayer{#1}%
  \llap{\secondlayer{#1}}%
  \llap{\thirdlayer{#1}}%
}

\usepackage{lettrine,lipsum}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{5}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFont}{\initialmaker}

\begin{document}
\lettrine{H}{ello world}
\lipsum[4]

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The output in the letter in the desired Goudy font but with a line height of one, not five.

[image: correct font but not the correct height]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was quite a stupid question, really. I fixed it by defining a new command:

```
\newcommand{\Lettrine}[2]{\lettrine[depth=1]{\initialmaker{#1}}{#2}}
```

The `depth` is required because the font now uses six lines instead of five causing the text to run over the bottom of the initial.