# To Color or Not to Color the Small-Capped Letters Following a Two-Color Lettrine---A Typography Question

Tags: color, typography, small-caps, lettrine, octavo

This question is directed to LaTeX typographers and is a bit of a follow-up to the one asked in  [Centering an Initfamily Letter within a Colorbox and Sizing It for Use as a Two-Color Lettrine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632584/centering-an-initfamily-letter-within-a-colorbox-and-sizing-it-for-use-as-a-two).

As probably everyone knows (and I just found out recently), placing a given color against a black background does produce the same hue as that same color put over a white background. In particular, consider, for example, the following code:

```
\documentclass[foolscap]{octavo}
\usepackage{lettrine,lmodern,xcolor}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\input GoudyIn.fd
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}

\fboxsep=0pt % padding thickness
\fboxrule=0pt % border thickness
\begin{document}
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.5,findent=.23em,nindent=4.5pt]{\fcolorbox{yellow}{olive!45!yellow}{T\kern-.04em}}{o} color or not to color the small caps letters following the lettrine; and if to color, aesthetically, which color to choose? \\[15pt]

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.5,findent=.23em,nindent=4.5pt]{\fcolorbox{yellow}{olive!45!yellow}{T\kern-.04em}}{\textbf{o}} color or not to color the small caps letters following the lettrine; and if to color, aesthetically, which color to choose? \\[15pt]

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.5,findent=.23em,nindent=4.5pt]{\fcolorbox{yellow}{olive!45!yellow}{T\kern-.04em}}{\textbf{\textcolor{olive!45!yellow}{o}}} color or not to color the small caps letters following the lettrine; and if to color, aesthetically, which color to choose? \\[15pt]
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

The color employed in producing the lettrine is `olive!45!yellow`. However, when I use `olive!45!yellow` in the third paragraph of the output, a much lighter, and I dare say, not aesthetically pleasing hue results in the colorized initials following the lettrine.

I have tried, unsuccessfully, to come up with some shade of olive using various combinations of olive, black, and yellow, but with nothing that strikes me as the right shade to accompany the 2-color lettrine displayed. I have also left the small-capped letters both without and with bold, as shown in the first two paragraphs respectively, but neither of which in my opinion, gives an optimal aesthetically pleasing answer.

As typography has been a rather popular tag on this site, I would like to ask the following question:

QUESTION: Given the displayed two-color lettrine, how might one best present the small-capped letters associated with it? --- As is, in the first paragraph; black bold as shown in the second paragraph; or some colorization as suggested in the third paragraph. I have a hunch that the third choice might be preferable here, but after many attempts at color variations, I have not stumbled upon one that seems right. If color-bold is the answer, could someone suggest a desirable color combination; if color-bold not the answer, what would be from a typographical viewpoint?

Thank you.

Comment: Definitely not bold. Color doesn’t look right either, unless you color a whole phrase, and even then its advisability depends on the nature of the text you’re setting in type. The small cap also looks wrong when it’s just a single character: include a phrase in the second argument of `\lettrine{...}{...}`.

Comment: Actually I deleted my first comment as @Thérèse made me realize why I didn't like the first, with just a single small cap o, I'd agree use the first but with more words in small caps.

Comment: @Thérèse  So, it seems that a consensus might be: (i) no bold small-caps; (ii) no small-caps for two-letter words. If I may ask, should/might anything special (color) be done for proper names (first and last)? Or definitely not? Thank you for your helpful comment.

Comment: @David Carlisle So, it seems that a consensus might be: (i) no bold small-caps; (ii) no small-caps for two-letter words. If I may ask, should/might anything special (color) be done for proper names (first and last)? Or definitely not? Thank you for your helpful comments.

Comment: The use of bold is a much more recent development than drop caps. Goudy’s initials evoke a time when bold would not have been used at all or would have been used quite sparingly. Small caps already give a text some emphasis, which means that bold small caps more or less scream at the reader. About proper names, you mean if they appear at the beginning of a text, where you’d want a drop cap, like `\lettrine{J}{ulius Caesar}`?

Comment: you didn't show bold small caps of course only bold lowercase. Personally I don't like the coloured version at all (especially that color which is virtually unreadable against a white background, perhaps I'm getting too old for this:-)

Comment: I agree with David about the color, and I’ve had enough students with low vision that I use only darker colors (like Maroon in `svgnames`) for text. Some PDF viewers let you see your text in grayscale, so that you can check whether the contrast suffices.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you; and for pointing out the bold lowercase (sorry about that). Actually, no color makes the job a lot easier, as the color of the lettrine will often times change from document to document---I hate to think of the grief that will cause me and time it will take to find a color that reasonably matches  a 2-color lettrine. I couldn't even find one for the above. :-) Thanks again.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you again for your most helpful comments. As for Julius Caesar---yes, should I leave such a thing as `\lettrine{J}{ulius Caesar}`?

Comment: If you’re using drop caps to mark the beginnings of new chapters and Caesar opens a chapter, I see no reason to make an exception for him.

Comment: @Thérèse Many thanks. You've helped me a lot.

Comment: I assume that your work is intended as a Ebook, rather than as print? Unless you are into high-end ($) printing, ordinary-size type may not print well (to paper) in color. In particular, if you use print-on-demand, it will be printed CMYK without spot colors.

Comment: At least, I would not use such a light color to style text. For the lettrine, the yellowish color is good, because it has a nice contrast to black, but against the white background of the paper, it is not that easy to read. But then, using another color also seems not the right way, because in my opinion the fewer different colors you use the better organised the overall result feels to the eye.

Comment: @rallg Thank you for this information.