# Specifying the Positioning Parameters for an egreg Two-Color Lettrine

Tags: color, positioning, parameters, lettrine, drop-cap

This post refers to a two-color lettrine provided by egreg in  [Centering an Initfamily Letter within a Colorbox and Sizing It for Use as a Two-Color Lettrine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632584/centering-an-initfamily-letter-within-a-colorbox-and-sizing-it-for-use-as-a-two).

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\definecolor{brownish}{RGB}{141, 81, 24}

\input{GoudyIn.fd}
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\newlength{\goudycorr}
\newcommand{\egreglettrine}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fontsize{85}{0}\initfamily
  \colorbox{black}{%
    \makebox[\height][l]{\color{brownish}#1}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=0.55]{\color{brownish}{\initfamily{T}}}{he Lorem ipsum} \lipsum[3]

\vspace*{20pt}

\noindent\egreglettrine{T} \textbf{egreg lettrine that I would like to make use of.}

\vspace*{20pt}

\noindent\egreglettrine{T}[lines=3,loversize=0.55]{\color{brownish}{\initfamily{T}}}{he Lorem ipsum} \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

The first paragraph displays an ordinary `initfamily` with positioning parameters `[lines=3,loversize=0.55]` given in the code.

The second paragraph of the output is the egreg lettrine that I would like to make use of in a document. However, specifying `\noindent\egreglettrine{T}[lines=3,loversize=0.55]{\color{brownish}{\initfamily{T}}}{he Lorem ipsum} \lipsum[3]` produces what we see in the third paragraph of the output.

QUESTION: Can someone advise me as to how to I can specify positioning parameters for the egreg lettrine according to those found in https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/lettrine/doc/lettrine.pdf according to David Carlisle’s keyval.sty syntax? i.e., analogous to the way in which they are specified for an ordinary lettrine.

Thank you.

Comment: it seems unrelated to egreg's code, in the second one you have used the optional arguments of `\lettrine` but not actually used `\lettrine`

Comment: your `\egreglettrine` isn't a lettrine (ie drop cap) at all it's just a big fancy T so use it in the first argument of `\lettrine` in place of `\initfamily{T}` which should be `\initfamily T` as it doesn't take an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You have simply omited the `\lettrine` command but used its optional argument, so the output is as if in the first case you had

```
%\lettrine
[lines=3,loversize=0.55]{\color{brownish}{\initfamily{T}}}{he Lorem ipsum} \lipsum[3]
```

Adding the `\lettrine` back and fixing the argument order, produces the effect above. The `\makebox` gave an error on nesting inside lettrine which is an unrelated issue but I just used a save box to avoid the nesting to save debugging lettrine internals.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\definecolor{brownish}{RGB}{141, 81, 24}

\input{GoudyIn.fd}
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\newlength{\goudycorr}
\newcommand{\egreglettrine}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fontsize{85}{0}\initfamily
  \colorbox{black}{%
    \makebox[\height][l]{\color{brownish}#1}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=0.55]{\color{brownish}{\initfamily{T}}}{he Lorem ipsum} \lipsum[3]

\vspace*{20pt}

%\noindent\egreglettrine{T} \textbf{egreg lettrine that I would like to make use of.}

\vspace*{20pt}

\sbox0{\egreglettrine{T}}%
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=0.55]{\usebox0}{he Lorem ipsum} \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

You probably want to adjust the space befpre He Lorem as in your previous question.

Comment: Many thanks @David Carlisle for this most helpful answer.