# Drop Cap individual settings, leave the main style of drop caps intact, but modify only certain (single) drop cap's parameters

Tags: formatting, cyrillic, lettrine, drop-cap

I set up all the parameters of existing Drop Caps in my `book` via `\DefaultLoversize` and `\DefaultLraise` commands and everything looks fine until the drop caps letter falls, for example, on this Cyrillic character `Д`. 
Instantly the problem occurs with the font descenders falling right on the text below the drop cap letter (see MWE).
I am happy with the current drop caps settings throughout the `book` (drop cap's top a bit over the first line and bottom exactly on the third line) and don't want to change it. I know that if I lower `\DefaultLoversize`, the `Д` character will look just fine but that will also change the size of all drop caps throughout the whole `book` and they will look awkwardly hanging (above the third line). 
So my question is: how do I modify the properties of only one single drop cap, leaving the rest of them intact?

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[
  SmallCapsFont={EB Garamond SC},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
  Ligatures=TeX,
]
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno} 
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=6in,
  paperheight=9in,
  inner=15mm,
  top=15mm,
  outer=20mm,
  bottom=22mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry} 

\usepackage{lettrine}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.1} 
\renewcommand{\DefaultLraise}{0} 
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{\fontdimen2\font}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\normalfont\large}{\thechapter.}{6pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{10pt plus 10pt}

\begin{document} 
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\frontmatter
    
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  \vspace*{10mm} 
  {\scshape\huge TITLE\par}
\end{titlepage}

\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{CHAPTER ONE}
\lettrine[lines=3]{Д}{orem} ipsum 
\lipsum[1-1]

\chapter{CHAPTER TWO}
\lettrine[lines=3]{L}{orem} ipsum 
\lipsum[1-1]
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have the needed fonts, but this answer may (or not) provide an alternative way to use lettrine drop caps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632584/centering-an-initfamily-letter-within-a-colorbox-and-sizing-it-for-use-as-a-two/632586#632586

Comment: You're right. I found a hint to the solution there. I'll post it as answer in case if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if anyone needs to know how to do it, the answer is simple: 
You can use the same parameters set for your whole document with any given Drop Cap specifically. 
Just modify your drop cap line at its specific location from `\lettrine[lines=3]{Д}{orem} ipsum` to `\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=-0.05,lraise=0.15]{Д}{orem} ipsum` replace the numbers with whatever suits you better and voila!