# Boundingbox for each Letter using lua code (follow-up question)

Tags: luatex, boxes

This is a follow-up question regarding [topskip's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58327/112503):

topskip's code works very well, even for complex documents (containing tables, pagination, footnotes etc.), nevertheless, as the following screenshot demonstrates, some of these elements do not get boxed.

[image]

Question:
Why isn't every letter boxed? What's wrong?

The screenshot is part of the result produced by this MWE (demo thesis, taken from berkeley):

```
%% thesis.tex 2014/04/11
% Source: https://math.berkeley.edu/~vojta/thesis/
% Integrated into one single file, extended using topskip's luaCharBox-code
%
\documentclass{ucbthesis}
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase,microtype,blindtext}
\begin{luacode*}
local GLYPH_ID = node.id("glyph")

-- head is a linked list (next/prev entries pointing to the next node)
-- parent it the surrounding h/vbox
function showcharbox(head,parent)
    while head do
        if head.id == 0 or head.id == 1 then
            -- a hbox/vbox
            showcharbox(head.list,head)
        elseif head.id == GLYPH_ID then
            r = node.new("rule")
            r.width  = head.width
            r.height = head.height
            r.depth  = head.depth

            -- replace the glyph by
            -- the rule by changing the
            -- pointers of the next/prev
            -- entries of the rule node
            if not head.prev then
                -- first glyph in a list
                parent.list = r
            else
                head.prev.next = r
            end

            head.next.prev = r
            r.prev = head.prev
            r.next = head.next

            -- now the glyph points to
            -- nowhere and we should remove
            -- it from the memory
            node.free(head)

            head = r
        end
        head = head.next
    end
    return true
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",showcharbox,"showcharbox")
\end{luacode*}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Jibberish}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}

That's fine until footnote:\footnote{Davidson witting and grammatic.}

\begin{theorem}
    \tolerance=10000\hbadness=10000
    This does not work.
\end{theorem}

That's fine again: Wash, Doff, and Algorithm.

\begin{itemize}
    \item Items work partially.
    \item Salutary.  Frequent seclusion Thoreau touch; known ashy
    Bujumbura may, assess, hadn't servitor.  Wash, Doff, and Algorithm.
\end{itemize}   
\end{document}
```

Note:
When using book, article, scrbook or scrartcl instead of ucbthesis class the page number does not get boxed.

### Bonus-MWE

It demonstrates the problem regarding the figure caption:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase,microtype,blindtext}
\begin{luacode*}
local GLYPH_ID = node.id("glyph")

-- head is a linked list (next/prev entries pointing to the next node)
-- parent it the surrounding h/vbox
function showcharbox(head,parent)
    while head do
        if head.id == 0 or head.id == 1 then
            -- a hbox/vbox
            showcharbox(head.list,head)
        elseif head.id == GLYPH_ID then
            r = node.new("rule")
            r.width  = head.width
            r.height = head.height
            r.depth  = head.depth

            -- replace the glyph by
            -- the rule by changing the
            -- pointers of the next/prev
            -- entries of the rule node
            if head.prev then
                head.prev.next = r
            else
                -- first glyph in a list
                parent.list = r
            end

            if head.next then
                head.next.prev = r
            end

            r.prev = head.prev
            r.next = head.next

            -- now the glyph points to
            -- nowhere and we should remove
            -- it from the memory
            node.free(head)

            head = r
        end
        head = head.next
    end
    return true
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",showcharbox,"showcharbox")
\end{luacode*}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\edef\sizetape{1cm}
\tikzstyle{tmtape}=[draw,minimum size=\sizetape]
\node [tmtape] (input) {blabla};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Hello World!}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Note: The page number isn't boxed any more, too.

Comment: _M_WE?.........

Comment: @topskip Sorry, my intention was to take a somewhat comp[ete|lex] document from stock. I reduced the mWE.

Comment: @topskip please have a look on the Bonus MWE I added: It should demonstrate the problem I mentioned regarding the figure caption. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bug in the code which causes the Lua loop to break. I have tried to assign `r` to `head.next.prev` even if `head` has no next pointer. The fix is to guard the assignment:

```
if head.next then
     head.next.prev = r
end
```

So the code is:

```
%% thesis.tex 2014/04/11
% Source: https://math.berkeley.edu/~vojta/thesis/
% Integrated into one single file, extended using topskip's luaCharBox-code
%
\documentclass{ucbthesis}
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase,microtype,blindtext}
\begin{luacode*}
local GLYPH_ID = node.id("glyph")

-- head is a linked list (next/prev entries pointing to the next node)
-- parent it the surrounding h/vbox
function showcharbox(head,parent)
    while head do
        if head.id == 0 or head.id == 1 then
            -- a hbox/vbox
            showcharbox(head.list,head)
        elseif head.id == GLYPH_ID then
            r = node.new("rule")
            r.width  = head.width
            r.height = head.height
            r.depth  = head.depth

            -- replace the glyph by
            -- the rule by changing the
            -- pointers of the next/prev
            -- entries of the rule node
            if head.prev then
                head.prev.next = r
            else
                -- first glyph in a list
                parent.list = r
            end

            if head.next then
              head.next.prev = r
            end

            r.prev = head.prev
            r.next = head.next

            -- now the glyph points to
            -- nowhere and we should remove
            -- it from the memory
            node.free(head)

            head = r
        end
        head = head.next
    end
    return true
end


luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",showcharbox,"showcharbox")
\end{luacode*}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Jibberish}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}

That's fine until footnote:\footnote{Davidson witting and grammatic.}

\begin{theorem}
    \tolerance=10000\hbadness=10000
    This does not work.
\end{theorem}

That's fine again: Wash, Doff, and Algorithm.

\begin{itemize}
    \item Items work partially.
    \item Salutary.  Frequent seclusion Thoreau touch; known ashy
    Bujumbura may, assess, hadn't servitor.  Wash, Doff, and Algorithm.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: text with black boxes]

---

To answer the bonus question: I don't know why the caption does not call the `post_linebreak_filter`, perhaps it is not broken into lines?!?

You can use the package `atbegshi` to get the complete contents of the page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{luacode,atbegshi}
\begin{luacode*}
local GLYPH_ID = node.id("glyph")

-- head is a linked list (next/prev entries pointing to the next node)
-- parent it the surrounding h/vbox
function showcharbox(head,parent)
    while head do
        if head.id == 0 or head.id == 1 then
            -- a hbox/vbox
            showcharbox(head.list,head)
        elseif head.id == GLYPH_ID then
            r = node.new("rule")
            r.width  = head.width
            r.height = head.height
            r.depth  = head.depth

            -- replace the glyph by
            -- the rule by changing the
            -- pointers of the next/prev
            -- entries of the rule node
            if head.prev then
                head.prev.next = r
            else
                -- first glyph in a list
                parent.list = r
            end

            if head.next then
              head.next.prev = r
            end

            r.prev = head.prev
            r.next = head.next

            -- now the glyph points to
            -- nowhere and we should remove
            -- it from the memory
            node.free(head)

            head = r
        end
        head = head.next
    end
    return true
end


\end{luacode*}
\AtBeginShipout {\directlua{showcharbox(tex.box["AtBeginShipoutBox"])}}%
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\fbox{x}
\caption{Hello World!}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

BTW: please make a *M* WE next time. The document doesn't need `microtype` nor `tikz` to show the problem. Even `blindtext` is not needed.