# Examples of luatex callback with lualatex

Tags: luatex, big-list

This is my first steps with luatex, and  I have tried to learn from this site how to  add "luatex callback" the problem is that I find only a few examples on `post_linebreak_filter` or `process_input_buffer` although the list of callback is long   http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Callbacks

My hope is to create a list of example which demonstrate how to use callback with lualatex

Comment: look at the chickenize package. Don't be fooled by the fact that the examples are silly (changing every word to chicken:-) It has lots of good examples of the major lua callbacks, I have found it helpful on numerous occasions, and it was a good test when we were incorporating luatexbase callback support into the core latex distribution.

Comment: Thank's, I thought it would be better to put them here  each callback  with a small example.

Comment: See https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-3/tb99isambert.pdf and https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100isambert.pdf (be aware the 'token_filter' is not avaliable any longer and the interface with latex is different, but both documents are very useful).

Comment: @SalimBou See this answer for an example usage of `post_linebreak_filter` https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58327/243.