# How to draw boundary boxes?

Tags: boxes

I read this wonderful [paper](https://www.math.lsu.edu/%7Eaperlis/publications/mathclap/perlis_mathclap_24Jun2003.pdf) by Alexander Perlis entitled "**A complement to `\smash`, `\llap`, and `\rlap`**". The author draws the boundary boxes that LaTeX uses for typesetting like so:

[image]

**Question:** How can I draw such boundary boxes? I want this to better understand the various modes like the `vertical` and `horizontal` modes. Hence I also need to know how to draw these in different modes and not just `math` mode.

Comment: Related: **(1)** https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57812, and **(2)** https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510850, and **(3)** https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2083.