# Is there any ways to show the bounding boxes of a TeX text?

Tags: text, box

I want to add bounding box to all texts (title/section/paragraph/footer) in the tex, but don't change anything else (for example the indentation, margin ...). In other words, I want to putting bounding box on the original pdf. How can I implement this? Thanks a lot.
(I had tried mdframed/framed/fbox/tcolorbox..., but found they all affected the origin layout.)

Comment: Welcome to [TSE](https://tex.stackexchange.com). Take look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57812/108724).

Comment: Thanks, but I want to put rectangle bounding box to complete content (like paragraph or single line), not character. Is there any way?

Comment: LaTeX doesn't really keep track of all that info.  Truth is, the position of anything is not fixed until the page is ready to be shipped.  That is why \tikzmark writes the location to the aux file for use in the next run.

Comment: I thought another way. May be I can add special codes (for example predefined `start` and `end` tagger to each text line), how can I implement this in tex? To be clear, what I want to do is to change several starting- and ending- characters of each text line to my predefined taggers. Thanks. Then I can use pdfminer to read the start-end pairs, and get the bounding box of each group.

Comment: Have a look at [showframe](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe), perhaps it helps.