# Give each letter a white background

Tags: color, backgrounds

I'm looking for something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58327/205203) except with a white background and no border.

Note that I have no Lua experience so if you can please don't use it `:)`

Comment: Do you mean setting the background colour of text? `\colorbox{}{}` does that: try `\colorbox{green!20}{l a b}` as a test. The linked question is about displaying the bounding boxes of glyphs.

Comment: @Cicada I mean doing that for each letter while respecting the spacing.